# Trouble implementing isalpha

Tags: c, cs50, isalpha

I've been working on the readability problem in CS50. The first step is to create a way to count only the alphabetical characters. It suggests to use the `isalpha` function, but doesn't really include directions on how to implement it.

Below is my code which succeeds in counting total alphabetical characters, but fails to filter out punctuation, spaces and integers.

Could anyone point me in a better direction to implement the `isalpha` so that it functions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h> 

int main(void)
{
    string s = get_string ("Text: \n");     // Ask for text

// Loop through the string one character at a time. Count strlen in variable n.
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(s); i < 1; i++) 

// Count only the alphabetical chars.
    {
        while (isalpha (n)) i++;
        printf ("%i", n );
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to be implementing `isalpha` yourself? The standard library contains its own implementation of it, which you can use since you have `#include <ctype.sh>`.

Comment: No- I am not sure.... I am totally new to this. How would I use the isalpha then if I don't specify it?

Comment: You didn't write `printf`, but you call it. `isalpha` is the same way.

Comment: I see... So when I delete the while and make that line 

isalpha (n); i++

I still get the same number.

Comment: Check what input you are giving to isalpha() and do you really need a while condition there ?

Comment: Does CS50 have a "string" type in the C-language?  Standard-C does not have a `string`.

Comment: @abelenky — for better or worse (and IMO not for better), CS50 does use a type `string` which is basically `typedef char *string;`.  Don't blame the students for that!!

Comment: Definitely not blaming the student, was just genuinely curious.  And I agree, it is for the worse:  an object of type `string` + 1 makes very little sense; an object of type `char*` + 1 is much more useful.   The more I learn about CS50, the less I like it.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char* s = get_string ("Text: \n");
    int count = 0;

    while(*s) count += !!isalpha(*s++);

    printf ("%d\n", count );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about a little explanation of the code provided?